# Vagrant docker chef_solo provision fail on CentOS and SuSe linux

Tags: docker, centos, vagrant, chef-solo, suse

i have Vagrant configuration with docker provider and chef-solo provision and after vagrant up --provider=docker command, Vagrant fail at chef_solo provision step:

**CentOS fail**

```
==> node1: Machine booted and ready!
==> node1: Running provisioner: chef_solo...
==> node1: Detected Chef (latest) is already installed
The chef binary (either `chef-solo` or `chef-client`) was not found on
the VM and is required for chef provisioning. Please verify that chef
is installed and that the binary is available on the PATH.
```

and **Suse fail**

```
==> node2: Machine booted and ready!
==> node2: Running provisioner: chef_solo...
node2: Installing Chef (latest)...
Vagrant attempted to execute the capability 'chef_install'
on the detect guest OS 'suse', but the guest doesn't
support that capability. This capability is required for your
configuration of Vagrant. Please either reconfigure Vagrant to
avoid this capability or fix the issue by creating the capability.
```

**Vagrantfile**

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.synced_folder "cnf/", "/home/vagrant/cnf_templates"

  config.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp"

  # node1 - CentOS 6.7
  config.vm.define "node1" do |node1|
    node1.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
      d.build_dir = "centos/"
      d.has_ssh = true
      #d.ports = ["3306:3306"]
      d.privileged = true
      #d.remains_running = false
    end

    node1.vm.provision "chef_solo" do |chef|
      chef.cookbooks_path = "../../../../recipes/cookbooks"
      chef.roles_path = "."
      chef.add_role "docker1"
    end
  end

  # node2 - OpenSuSE 13
  config.vm.define "node0" do |node2|
    node2.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
      d.build_dir = "sles/"
      d.has_ssh = true
      #d.ports = ["3306:3306"]
      d.privileged = true
    end

    node2.vm.provision "chef_solo" do |chef|
      chef.cookbooks_path = "../../../../recipes/cookbooks"
      chef.roles_path = "."
      chef.add_role "docker2"
    end
  end
end
```

**Dockerfile for CentOS**

```
FROM centos:6.7

#ENV SHELL /bin/bash

RUN yum update -y && \
    yum clean all && \
    yum --assumeyes install openssh-server openssh-clients sudo curl wget iptables
    yum clean all

RUN /etc/init.d/sshd start

RUN sed -i 's/.*requiretty$/Defaults !requiretty/' /etc/sudoers

# Create and configure vagrant user
RUN groupadd vagrant && \
    useradd -c "Vagrant" -g vagrant -d /home/vagrant -m -s /bin/bash vagrant &&
    echo 'vagrant:vagrant' | chpasswd && \
    mkdir -p /etc/sudoers.d && \
    echo 'vagrant       ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers.d/vagrant
    chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/vagrant

# Configure SSH access
RUN mkdir -pm 700 /home/vagrant/.ssh && \
    echo 'ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEA6NF8iallvQVp22WDkTkyrtvp9eWW6A8YV
    chmod 0600 /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys && \
    chown -R vagrant:vagrant /home/vagrant/.ssh

# Clean up when done.
#RUN yum clean all

# daemonize sshd
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D", "-e"]
EXPOSE 22
```

**Dockerfile for Suse**

```
FROM opensuse:latest

RUN zypper -n --gpg-auto-import-keys ar http://download.opensuse.org/factory/repo/oss/ OSS

RUN zypper -n ref && \
    zypper -n up --skip-interactive && \
    zypper --non-interactive --gpg-auto-import-keys install -y openSSH sudo wget iptables SuSefirewall2

ENV SHELL /bin/bash

RUN sed -i 's/UsePAM no/UsePAM yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN sed -i 's/#PubkeyAuthentication no/PubkeyAuthentication yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
#RUN sed -i 's/#ChallengeResponseAuthentication no/ChallengeREsponseAuthentication ...
RUN sed -i 's/#PermitRootLogin yes/PermitRootLogin no/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
#RUN echo 'root:13579Rh' | chpasswd

CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "rcsshd restart"]

RUN sed -i 's/.*requiretty$/Defaults !requiretty/' /etc/sudoers

# Create and configure vagrant user
RUN groupadd vagrant && \
    useradd -m -g vagrant -d /home/vagrant -s /bin/bash vagrant && \
    echo 'vagrant:vagrant' && \
    echo 'vagrant       ALL=(ALL)       ALL' >> /etc/sudoers.d/vagrant && \
    chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/vagrant

# create ssh host keys for sshd
RUN ssh-keygen -A

# Configure SSH access
RUN mkdir -p /home/vagrant/.ssh && \
    echo 'ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEA6NF8iallvQVp22WDkTkyrtvp9eWW6A8YV$
    chmod 0600 /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys && \
    chown -R vagrant:vagrant /home/vagrant/.ssh && \
    chmod 0700 /home/vagrant/.ssh

# Install chef
#RUN wget -O - https://www.opscode.com/chef/install.sh | /bin/bash

# Clean up APT when done.
#zypper clean
#RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
EXPOSE 22
```

What's wrong with my configuration? I tryed almost all chef version install: omnibus plugin, manual chef install by bash script (wget chef.sh | bash) and basic chef provision.

P.S. Chef-solo works fine only on Ubuntu 14.04 with vagrant docker provider.

Thanks,
Kirill

Comment: Where is chef getting installed in the CentOS provisioning? Where does `chef-solo` or `chef-client` normally live on CentOS? Is it there if you look for it manually? What does `$PATH` contain?

Comment: Yes, chef-solo installed in CentOS. If i go by ssh to the container, chef-solo already exists in it. $PATH variable does not contain path to the chef dir (/opt/chef/bin) and this dir under root. I tryed to add a chef path to $PATH manually, but it didn't work out.

Comment: How did you try adding to `$PATH`? It seems like that's the problem with the provisioning and fixing that should work. Alternatively, if you can instruct vagrant what the full path to `chef-solo` is that might be worth trying.

Comment: I am trying to add $PATH by this lines in Dockerfile:
ENV PATH $PATH:/opt/chef/bin:/opt/chef/embedded/bin
RUN export PATH

Yes, i think so to, that problem in provisioning. How can i make it, add full path to the chef-solo by vagrant or it can be point in Dockerfile?

Comment: Without knowing docker that certainly seems like it should have worked (if that was done early enough). I don't know. I don't even know if that is possible. It was just a suggestion.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will continue to undestand this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, just use chef-container or install recipe manual by chef-solo and shell provision script:

RUN curl -L https://www.opscode.com/chef/install.sh | bash -s -- -P container